# Confusion with space and time usage

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

The following is my own set-up code:

```
Search_and_Sum(key, A,n)    A[1..n]
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=n+n+1000; i++){
        for(int j=A.length; j>=1; j/=2){
            if(key==A[j]) break;
            else          sum+=j;
        }
    }
    return sum;
```

Well, I think the first loop has time complexity $O(n)$ and the inner loop has time complexity $O(log\ n)$, so in the worst case, the running time is $O(n\ log\ n)$.

But, I can't figure out how to find the running time in the best case. Any ideas?

Edit:

Is this is an equivalent formulation of the code with the same running time?

```
Search_and_Sum(key, A,n)    A[1..n]
    int sum = 0;
    int k = A.length;
    while(k>=1 && key!=A[k]){
        sum=*key;
        k/=2;
        }
    }
    return sum;
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? The inner loop doesn't depend on `i` at all, so the code is just "Do this $2n+1000$ times." Since the inner loop doesn't depend on `i`, the best case occurs just when the last element of `A` is `key`.

Comment: Well, I intentionally decided to make the inner loop independent of i. I can now see how the best case becomes $\Omega(n)$ because in the best case, the inner loop just runs a single time.

Comment: I've been trying to rewrite the code using a while loop. Can you please check if my following edit is an equivalent formulation?

Comment: 1) Be wary of your formulation. The "first loop" does not have "complexity" $O(n)$; it *includes* the second, inner loop, so it has the total "complexity". Think in terms of "how many iterations?". See our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) on how to translate your code to mathematics; the best-case input is for you to determine (but mathematics can guide you: what `A` minimizes the expression?). See also [tag:runtime-analysis+loops].